# Is removing an element from the front of a list cheap in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, optimization

I am writing a program, that does a lot of deletions at either the front or back of a list of data, never the middle.

I understand that deletion of the last element is cheap, but how about deletion of the first element? For example let's say list `A`'s address is at `4000`, so element `0` is at `4000` and element `1` is at `4001`.

Would deleting element `0` then just make the compiler put list `A`'s address at `4001`, or would it shift element `1` at `4001` to the location at `4000`, and shift all other elements down by `1`?

Comment: No, it resizes when you delete form the middle or front. Also, a Python list is not equivalent to a C-array. Although, deep down, there is an array of Py_Object pointers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, it isn't cheap. Removing an element from the front of the list (using `list.pop(0)`, for example) is an `O(N)` operation and *should be avoided*. Similarly, inserting elements at the beginning (using `list.insert(0, <value>)`) is equally inefficient.

This is because, after the list is resized, it's elements must be shifted. For CPython, in the `l.pop(0)` case, [this is done with `memmove`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L651) while for `l.insert(0, <value>)`, [the shifting is implemented with a loop through the items stored](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L267).

Lists are built for fast *random access* and `O(1)` operations on their *end*.

---

Since you're doing this operation commonly, though, you should consider using a [`deque` from the `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (as @ayhan suggested in a comment). The docs on `deque` also highlight how `list` objects aren't suitable for these operations:

> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for *fast fixed-length operations* and *incur `O(n)` memory movement costs for `pop(0)` and `insert(0, v)`* operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The `deque` data structure  offers `O(1)` complexity for both sides (beginning and end) with `appendleft`/`popleft` and `append`/`pop` methods for the beginning and end respectively.

Of course, with small sizes this incurs some extra space requirements (due to the structure of the `deque`) which should generally be of no concern (and as @juanpa noted in a comment, doesn't always hold) as the sizes of the lists grow. Finally, as @ShadowRanger's insightful comment notes, with really small sequence sizes the problem of popping or inserting from the front is trivialized to the point that it becomes of really no concern.

So, in short, for lists with many items, use `deque` if you need fast appends/pops from both sides, else, if you're randomly accessing and appending to the end, use `list`s.

Comment: Actually, in my experience, `deque`s are *smaller* than lists. Try a simple test, `for i in range(0, 10000000, 100000): l,d = list(range(i)), deque(range(i)); print(sys.getsizeof(l), sys.getsizeof(d))`. the list is always slightly larger.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're using the `list` initializer which always creates larger lists, try it with a comprehension (or a literal, for smaller lists) and provide that to `deque` and count the sizes again. There seems to be some discrepancies in larger sizes (probably due to how these allocate memory) but in general, the assertion that in smaller sizes the list is smaller I believe holds.

Comment: I actually did try it with the list-comprehension. Last reading: `81528056 82500632`. Essentially, in this case the list-comprehension will optimize the storage, and there are runs of lists having the same size. At the beginning of the run, it is slightly smaller than the equivalent deque. By the middle of the run, the deque is smaller. It probably averages to about a wash. But basically, my conclusion is that deques are usually smaller or about the same size.

Comment: Actually, it the lists are *bigger* at the *beginning* of the run, smaller relative to the deque at the end.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard it's actually a fact that I found stunning when I first stumbled onto it. It has definitely made me feel better about my use of `deque`s in my code. I previously had assumed it was incurring a significant memory penalty across the board. The biggest penalty, of course, is to element access.

Comment: Note: For a sequence that never grows beyond single digit lengths, it hardly matters if you use `list` or `deque`; sure, `pop`ing from the front will be `O(n)`, but when `n` is `6`, the fixed overhead of Python outweighs any benefit of avoiding the `memmove`, and in fact, the fact that new `deque` blocks would be allocated intermittently for the `deque` as you reach the end of the current block (where a `list` with a narrow range of lengths would never need to reallocate) would make the performance less consistent. Until lengths are meaningful, it's just noise compared to interpreter overhead.

Comment: For huge N, list_.pop(0) isn't good - but for smallish sizes, list_.pop(0) can actually be a good way to go due to cache effects.  This is why sorteddict is so much faster than most traditional kinds of trees.  I believe collections.deque uses some of the same trickery for performance - instead of being a simple, doubly-linked list, it's a doubly-linked list where each element is a list (?) of M elements.

Answer (score 16):

Removing elements from the front of a list in Python is O(n), while removing elements from the ends of a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is only O(1). A deque would be great for your purpose as a result, however it should be noted that accessing or adding/removing from the middle of a deque is more costly than for a list.

The O(n) cost for removal is because a list in CPython is simply implemented as an array of pointers, thus your intuition regarding the shifting cost for each element is correct.

This can be seen in the [Python TimeComplexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Wiki.